# What .js Do I Need to Include to Access Cordova's Media object?

Tags: cordova, icenium

I'm using Icenium Mist, and the cordova.js it includes is pretty streamlined and small and I can't find the definition of the Media object I'm hoping to use.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project properties in Mist and choose "plugins". Check the box to include the media plugin and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

Media object is provided in a plugin.
You need to include this one: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media
Not sure how to do it with Icenium Mist but with the command line tools it is:
Cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media

See http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media for more details.
And here for http://docs.icenium.com/creating-your-project/using-plugins/working-with-plugins for more details about adding the plugin

Edit:
If I read the docs for icenium correctly you need to do the following:

1. In the Project Navigator, double-click Properties.
2. In the Plugins tab, navigate to the Core Plugins section and expand it, if needed.
3. Check or uncheck the plugins you need

Edit2:

Does it work when you execute it in the deviceready event like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    var media = new Media(src, successcallback);
}, false);
```

of course changing the parameters to your need

Comment: Hmm . . . if "Media" in core plug-ins is the same thing as the cordova-plugin-media on Github, it's already checked and turned on!

Comment: "Media is not defined" is the error I get when I try to use something like "var media = new Media(src, successCallback, etc)".  This is in the Icenium Mist simulator.  Would the Media object be available only when running on true iOS, perhaps?

Comment: Is you're code executed after device ready? See http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready